# how to drag and drop multiple different style shapes in android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, drawable

I am attempting to drag and drop shapes in android. I am using a gridview with alows for 4 separate sections on screen. I am using the android ic-launcher for image. I can drag and drop each image to other sections of the gridview, but I want to have multiple shapes in each section of the gridview, the idea is that they are mixed up so the user has to drag and drop them to they have all circles in one section, squares in another and so on, I hope u get my idea so far! I have attached my shape.xml, shape_droptarget.xml, main.xml and my activity.java. I have tried a few things but just not sure how to go about it. Any ideas that could send me in the correct direction would be really helpful. thanks

**shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="225"
        android:endColor="#DD2ECCFA"
        android:startColor="#DD000000" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

</shape>
```

**shape.droptarget.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FFFF0000" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="225"
        android:endColor="#DD2ECCFA"
        android:startColor="#DD000000" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

</shape>
```

**main.xml**

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:columnWidth="300dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topleft"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topright"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomleft"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomright"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>
```

**DragActivity.java**

```
public class DragActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        findViewById(R.id.myimage1).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.myimage2).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.myimage3).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.myimage4).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
        findViewById(R.id.topleft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.topright).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.bottomleft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
        findViewById(R.id.bottomright).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    }

    private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
          if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }

    class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
        Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
        Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
          int action = event.getAction();
          switch (event.getAction()) {
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            // Do nothing
            break;
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
            break;
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
            break;
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            owner.removeView(view);
            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
            container.addView(view);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
          case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
          default:
            break;
          }
          return true;
        }
      }

}
```